# Loading XML File

Tags: xml

I'm using xml to store cross-program information. This information is used in some webpages and in C# programs. When the information is altered, these alterations are not displayed right away in the webpages, they keep on displaying the information saved in cache, it takes a few refreshes for the webpage to show these alterations. Is there any way I can force the webpages to show the actual file and not the cached one?

Comment: Normally specific coding questions would be migrated to Stack Overflow, however, this is too vague a question for there.

Comment: I didn't post it there because of that... :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pages are cached.  Put a meta line in the header saying that they expire very soon, and they should get reloaded.

Comment: More specifically: `<meta http-equiv="expires" 
content="0">`

Comment: Certain versions of IE ignore that tag